# Forcing child widget to inherit its parent's style in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

Many flutter widgets forces their child to inherit their style, like:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Click Me."),
    onPressed: (){},
);
```

this `ElevatedButton()` will force its `Text()` child to inherit a specific text color, weight and so on...

My question is how to make a widget that forces its child to inherit a style from it, and Thank you ^^.

I tried using `Theme` widget but it's useless.

Comment: "style" is a very broad concept. Could you explain more what properties of the parent widget are you trying to pass to the child widget?

Comment: @JerZaw
like TextStyle from the parent to the  child.

Comment: In that case you could use an outside function that generates the TextStyle, and return the widget to both locations

Comment: see [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) - the docs say: "The text style to apply to descendant Text widgets which don't have an explicit style."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) mentioned in the comments [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) worked well.